# How to initialize angular.js controller data inline the "right" way

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm aware of how to do this with a promise on an http request, but in this case, the data must be initialized from an inline script.

This controller is already defined in the header js:

```
var testModule = angular.module('myTestModule', []);
testModule.controller('testCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = [];
});
```

The following html loads, and for sake of argument, let's say it takes a very long time to finish the script part:

```
<div ng-app="myTestModule" ng-controller="testCtrl">
...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInitialData(['boo', 'far']);
</script>
```

If the inline script were loaded BEFORE the div with ng-app, I wouldn't be having an issue, but in this case it may load after the controller has been instantiated. I'm trying to avoid an extra http request, though it's convenient to utilize a promise with an angular service.

Does anyone have any ideas for how to construct the function setInitialData so that it applies the data to the controller/scope?

Comment: The "right" way, as you mention, is to make an AJAX request as you've already mentioned

Comment: It just seems wasteful to make two requests when the data is available to the application while fulfilling the first request.

Comment: I realize the question is about how to get the inline script to work, but why? Have you considered calling setInitializedData from inside your controller or your app's run block?

Comment: It has to do with custom framework restrictions. Javascript is put into a separate content block beyond the main body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `angular.element(...).scope()` method to get a reference to the scope for any DOM element (protip: use `angular.element($0).scope()` in the devtools JS console to get the scope for the currently selected element in the Elements tab).

From there you can make changes to the scope as required. Make sure to call `$apply()` to make AngularJS aware of the change.

e.g.

```
<div ng-app="myTestModule" ng-controller="testCtrl" id="testCtrl">
...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setScopeValue(selector, scopeProp, value) {
        angular.element(selector).scope().$apply(function ($scope) {
            $scope[scopeProp] = value;
        });
    }

    function setInitialData(data) {
        setScopeValue('#testCtrl', 'data', data);
    }

    setInitialData(['boo', 'far']);
</script>
```

Note that my `setScopeValue()` function only works for a single level of property access, so dots are not supported. If you needed to set nested properties, you would want to use `$parse()` to create a setter function you can call with the `$scope` and the value to set.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. There is one caveat; jqLite won't work with the '#testCtrl' selector. I ended up using angular.element(document.getElementById(id))